# How do I use pfquery in parse.com filtering on a boolean field in ios?

Tags: objective-c, ios, boolean, parse-platform

doing a query in an ios/objective c app against a Parse.com datasource how do I construct my PFQuery to filter on a boolean column?

I have something like this;

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MyClass"];
[query whereKey:@"MyBoolCol" equalTo:TRUE];
```

How do I construct this please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
[query whereKey:@"MyBoolCol" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

Comment: Sorry, been away - Queen's Jubilee an' all! ;)