# PFQuery Matches Query not Working Parse.com

Tags: ios, tableview, parse-platform

Hello everyone I'm trying to merge two queries with MatchesQuery but the data on the TableView will not be displayed and gives me this error

**Error: bad type for $ inquery**

Does anyone know what is the error in this query? Thanks to all

```
- (void) retrieveFromParse {

    PFQuery *Amici = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Amicizie"];
    [Amici whereKey:@"RICHIESTA_IN_ATTESA" equalTo:@"YES"];

    PFQuery *retrievePets = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:FF_USER_CLASS];
    [retrievePets whereKey:FF_USER_NOMECOGNOME matchesQuery:Amici];
    [retrievePets orderByAscending:FF_USER_NOMECOGNOME];


    [retrievePets findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", objects);
            allObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                [allObjects addObject:object];
            }
        }
        [self.FFTableViewFindUser reloadData];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Could you add to your question the schema, in particular for class `FF_USER_CLASS` what is the type of column `FF_USER_NOMECOGNOME`? Also is the type of `Amicizie.RICHIESTA_IN_ATTESA` a string or boolean? You're doing a string match query, but it looks like you might mean to use a boolean.

Comment: The Boolean value of which I speak is a value that is invoked when the user clicks the button in the TableView and its function is going to add this in the class Boolean Friends ... It has only one function to hold a friend request. (The Boolean class is _USER but in another class Parse.com "Friends").

Comment: If the user has clicked the button and then sent the request I wanted to use the boolean to clear the button that the user has previously clicked ... This is the function that I wanted to create, because I'm trying to do what you suggested long ago to the demands of friendship :)

Comment: The RICHIESTA_IN_ATTESA is a Boolean Value ..:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are querying on a boolean value, you should look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852841/how-do-i-use-pfquery-in-parse-com-filtering-on-a-boolean-field-in-ios).

Basically you need to do this:

```
[Amici whereKey:@"RICHIESTA_IN_ATTESA" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

That may be all you need. If not it will get you another error message to help you get to the root of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a "amiciString" column which holds the string value. Then you can do this:

```
[retrievePets whereKey:@"FF_USER_NOMECOGNOME" matchesKey:@"amiciString" inQuery:Amici];
```

Try! I hope it works!

Comment: I did the query but my table is completely white ... : (

Comment: Initialize the array `allObjects = [NSMutableArray array];`